# Cannot load the custom visualizer in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, debuggervisualizer

I've created a custom visualizer in Visual Studio 2019 but I'm having trouble activating it on a specific machine (it works on two other machines, so it's not related to the code).
I've placed the visualizer (called DocumentVisualizer.dll) in the *MyDocuments\Visual Studio 2019\Visualizer* folder and at debug, when checking the object I see the magnifying glass as expected.

But when I click on it, this is the error I see *Unable to load the custom visualizer*
[image]

It mentions that the issue could be related to *Microsoft.VisualStudio.DebuggerVisualizers.dll* version but I'm not sure of how to check this. (I've installed only Visual Studio 2019 on this machine)

This appears to be a machine-specific problem as I could load the visualizer on a couple of other machines.

Any clues on how to fix that?

I've tried cleaning the output, restarting the machine and reinstalling Visual Studio with no success.

Comment: Have you had any success in figuring this out? If so, do you remember the solution?